# How to add a class to father element when it's child is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add class with jQuery to an li when a span selector inside it is getting clicked.

What I've done so far:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('li span').click(function() {
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');

  });
});

<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Hello World</a>
    <span></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This of course adds the class to the span itself. 
I can't figure out how to reach his father -> the li

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use the `.parent()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [.parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) to access parent element

```
jQuery(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [.parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) to select the parent element like so

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('li span').click(function() {
    jQuery(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
  });
});

<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Hello World</a>
    <span></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```